# I want those customers present in the data frame which has more false value than true value .Any suggestion on how to achieve that

Tags: pandas, dataframe, solution

The data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust1',
                            'cust2', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2','cust2','cust1'],
                       'B': ['true', 'true', 'true', 'false',
                            'false', 'false', 'false', 'true','false','true']})
```

Ouput : ['cust2']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get counts by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and then filter `index` values by columns with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for greater is used [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'])
print (df1)
B      false  true
A                 
cust1      2     3
cust2      3     2

c = df1.index[df1['false'].gt(df1['true'])].tolist()
#if True, False are boolean
#c = df1.index[df1[False].gt(df1[True])].tolist()
print (c)
['cust2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['B']=='false'].groupby(['A']).count().sort_values(by['A'],ascending=False).index[0]
```

Explanation: Take all values with only 'False', groupby 'A' and count. Now sort the value in descending order and get the first index('A') value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the case of multi -indexing so you can use index to isolate the greater value :

```
list = list(dataframe.index[dataframe['false'].gt(dataframe['true'])])
```